# Max-height reached and the div continuesly goes to right like responsive overflow-x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to achieve this layout, Can show me how to that?

[image]

**CSS**

```
.broad-structure{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 450px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    white-space: normal;
}

.broad-content{
    padding: 30px;
}

.structure .veno{
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.desc-pro{
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.story{
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: justify;
}

.nodes{
    background-color: rgba(221, 213, 213, 0.11);
     height: 100%;
}

.grayz{
    background-color: rgba(221, 213, 213, 0.11);
}

.fishy{
   background-color: rgba(221, 213, 213, 0.11);
     height: 100%; 
}

.chandelier{
    padding: 30px;
}

.tagline img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}

.cont-struct{
    height: 850px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.viso{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 420px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    white-space: normal;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.construct{
    padding: 30px;
}

.construct h3{
    color: rgba(104, 109, 132, 0.58);
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn-nero {
    width: 88%;
}

.setia{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/taz931mm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this layout..

add these styles to your wrapper element display: flex ; flex-direction:column; flex-wrap:wrap; and it give it the height and width that you want for the wrapper.

Then in the child put height:200px( or whatever ) and then when the wrapper cannot hold any more elements it will push them onto the next column..

```
<style>

        .broad-structure {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
         .broad-content{
            height: 150px;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: I already post the demo. That is the relevant html that i'm using.

Comment: the heights used are just to show the effect so you can adjust the heights as per your design requirements..